# c++ udp recvfrom eventually hangs over remote connection

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, recvfrom

I'm writing a client server udp application in c++.  The application works correctly when the client and server are running on the same machine, however when I run my client on my laptop and the server on an ec2 instance in AWS, the server receives 4 messages and then begins to hang on `recvfrom`.  The client is sending a file in chunks of 500 bytes and the server is writing these to a file. The server sends an `ack` after it receives each chunk. The client has a timeout of 2 seconds, if it does not receive the `ack` before the timeout it resends the previous chunk. Here is my client code

```
void Sender::send_file(const char* host) {
cout << "in send file\n";
int sock = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
size_t length = 8;
unsigned char res_buf[8] = {0};
if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    std::cout << "\n Socket creation error \n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = timeout;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

// copy 0 into serv_addr members
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

size_t file_size = buffer.size();
cout << "file size " << to_string(file_size) << "\n";
size_t file_pos = 0;
int next_iteration = 1;
bool establish = true;
while(file_pos < file_size - 1) {
    cout << "waiting for lock\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mrun);
    main_ready.wait(lock, [&next_iteration, this]{return next_iteration == current_iteration; });
    lock.unlock();
    cout << "acquired lock\n";
    ++next_iteration;
    Segment segment;
    vector<unsigned char> req_str;
    if(!establish) {
        if(file_pos + mss < file_size) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> file_chunk(buffer.begin() + file_pos, buffer.begin() + file_pos + mss);
            segment.data = file_chunk;
            file_pos += mss;
        }
        else {
            std::vector<unsigned char> file_chunk(buffer.begin() + file_pos, buffer.end());
            segment.data = file_chunk;
            file_pos = file_size;
        }
        segment.seq_num = file_pos - mss;
        req_str = segment.to_bytes(false, mss);
    }
    else {
        segment.seq_num = 0;
        req_str = segment.to_bytes(true, mss);
    }

    bool is_ack = false, timed_out = false;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start_time, end_time;
    long duration = 0;
    unsigned char* req = req_str.data();
    size_t num_bytes = req_str.size();
    unsigned int len = 0;
    while(!is_ack) {
        cout << "about to send data " << std::to_string(segment.seq_num) << " bytes " << std::to_string(num_bytes) << "\n";
        ssize_t send_res = sendto(sock, req, num_bytes, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        printf("Sent to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));
        cout << "send res " << to_string(send_res) << " " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        bzero(res_buf, length);
        cout << "about to read ack\n";
        ssize_t block_sz = recvfrom(sock, res_buf, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &len);
        cout << "read ack\n";
        end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
        cout << "block sz " << std::to_string(block_sz) << " duration " << std::to_string(duration) << std::endl;
        if(duration > timeout * 1000)
            timed_out = true;
        if(timed_out || errno == ETIMEDOUT || block_sz < 0) {
            std::cout << "time out/error occurred on read " << to_string(errno) << "\n";
            cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
            bzero(res_buf, length);
            timed_out = false;
            continue;
        }
        //add_nulls(res_buf);
        is_ack = read_response(segment.seq_num, res_buf);
        cout << "is ack " << is_ack << "\n\n";
        bzero(res_buf, length);
    }
    establish = false;
    lock.lock();
    if(--worker_count == 0) {
        lock.unlock();
        iteration_complete.notify_one();
    }
}
cout << "Out of while loop\n";
close(sock);
files_sent.push_back(1);
}
```

It's sending exactly 508 bytes every time, except for the 1st segment which is only 10 bytes.  I print the results of sendto after every iteration which always looks like this

```
Sent to 52.0.0.0:7735
send res 508 Undefined error: 0
```

***   **Update** ***
Once the server begins to hang in `recvfrom` and the client times out waiting for the `ack`, the client begins to print the following error continuously as it keeps resending the chunk.

```
Sent to 52.0.0.0:7735
send res 508 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

The server code looks like

```
 void Receiver::download_file() {
int server_fd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int segment_size = 20;
umap seg_map;
ACK_Segment::init_static();
std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0.0, 1.0);
if((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == 0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// bind socket to port
//bzero(buffer, segment_size);
ssize_t block_sz = 0;
unsigned int len = sizeof cli_addr;
bool is_set_mss = true;
if(bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//unsigned char* buffer = bvec.data();
vector<unsigned char> bvec(segment_size);
unsigned char* buffer = bvec.data();
bool is_resized = false;
while(true) {
    cout << "about to recvfrom\n";
    printf("Receiving from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
    cout << "segment size " << to_string(segment_size) << " len " << to_string(len) << "\n";
    block_sz = recvfrom(server_fd, buffer, segment_size, 0, ( struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &len);
    cout << "block size " << to_string(block_sz) << "errno " << to_string(errno) << " " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    if(block_sz > 0) {
        cout << "Received data - bytes " << std::to_string(block_sz) << "\n";
        printf("Received from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
        double rand_val = dis(gen);
        if(is_set_mss) {
            seg_map = read_segment(bvec, block_sz, true);
            if(seg_map["checksum_valid"] == "true") {
                segment_size = mss + HEADER_SIZE;
                is_resized = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(block_sz == 0) {
                cout << "received no data\n";
                break;
            }
            seg_map = read_segment(bvec, block_sz, false);
        }
        if(seg_map["checksum_valid"] == "false")
            cout << "invalid checksum\n";
        else if(is_set_mss) {
            vector<unsigned char> ack = get_ack();
            //remove_nulls(ack);
            unsigned char* ack_bytes = ack.data();
            cout << "about to send ack\n";
            sendto(server_fd, ack_bytes, 8, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, len);
            //send(new_socket, ack, 8, 0);
            is_set_mss = false;
        }
        else {
            if(seg_map["in_order"] == "true") {
                string data = seg_map["data"];
                std::ofstream out;
                out.open(file_name, std::ios_base::app);
                out << data;
                out.close();
        cout << "Done writing file chunk\n";
            }
            vector<unsigned char> ack = get_ack();
            unsigned char* ack_bytes = ack.data();
            sendto(server_fd, ack_bytes, 8, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, len);
        }
        if(is_resized) {
            bvec.resize(segment_size);
            is_resized = false;
        }
        bvec.clear();
        buffer = bvec.data();
    cout << "Cleared buffer\n\n";
    }
    cout << "out of inner while\n";
}
}
```

This prints

```
Receiving from 168.0.0.0:18832
segment size 508 len 16
block size 508 errno 0 Success
```

However it only prints this 4 times, then it hangs on recvfrom while the client continues to send 508 bytes, and the segment size remains at 508 in `recvfrom`.  Why would recvfrom start out working and then all of the sudden stop?

**Update**

I watered this down to the simplest udp client server I could write,  here is the client:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::to_string;

int main() {
    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    size_t length = 11;
    unsigned char res_buf[11] = {0};
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        std::cout << "\n Socket creation error \n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

    // copy 0 into serv_addr members
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(7735);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("52.71.240.175");

    vector<unsigned char> req(20);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        req[i] = 'A';
    unsigned char* req_str = req.data();
    size_t num_bytes = req.size();
    unsigned int len = sizeof serv_addr;
    while(true) {
        cout << "about to send data\n";
        ssize_t send_res = sendto(sock, req_str, num_bytes, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        bzero(res_buf, length);
        cout << "about to read ack\n";
        ssize_t block_sz = recvfrom(sock, res_buf, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, &len);
        cout << "received " << res_buf <<  "\n";
    }
}
```

And here is the server:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::to_string;

int main() {
    int server_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int segment_size = 20;
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));

    if((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(7735);

    unsigned int len = sizeof cli_addr;
    if(bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    vector<unsigned char> bvec(segment_size);
    unsigned char* buffer = bvec.data();
    while(true) {
        cout << "about to receive from\n";
        ssize_t block_sz = recvfrom(server_fd, buffer, segment_size, 0, ( struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &len);
        if(block_sz > 0) {
            printf("Received from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));
            char* ack_bytes = "ack message";
            cout << "about to send ack\n";
            sendto(server_fd, ack_bytes, 11, 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, len);
        }
    }
}
```

And the same behavior happens, the server receives 4 messages, but then on the fifth message it just hangs in `recvfrom`.  I've tried closing and reopening the socket in each iteration on the server, that had no effect.

Comment: I don't understand how your server can display a correct client address in `Receiving from` before actually receiving the first message.

Comment: The very first log message on the server says `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Your client expects some `ack` messages from the server, but this latter  does not seem to send them (according to the provided source code). Do you see the timeouts happening? Does the provided source code really match with the observed behaviour of the program? It's very hard to guess what is not written down.

Comment: Yes the timeouts are happening on the client side and the message is continually re-sent while the server is just stuck on rcvfrom.  The client continues to print the log message I show in my post over and over. The code is pretty long, I tried to just put in the relevant portions.  The server is sending the `ack` messages, I didn't show that above, the client receives the first 4 and then the server does not send anymore because it is stuck in recvfrom.  I think its important to reiterate that this works correctly when both are running on the same ec2 instance.

Comment: I just posted the complete code

Comment: Punch [Sorceror's Apprentice Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice_Syndrome) into your favorite search engine. Your code can get into a failure mode where the sender keeps reading the receiver's *previous* ACK rather than its latest one.

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly something to keep an eye on, however the client is continuously sending data to the server but the server is not receiving it. If its reading the previous ACK that could result in incorrect data being sent, but I still expect the server to receive it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to close and reopen the socket on the client side after receiving each ack from the server.  I didn't need to close and reopen on the server side.  I'm not sure if this addresses the root cause of the problem I was facing but it allows my application to run correctly.

Comment: [this article](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/packets-per-second-in-ec2-vs-amazons-published-network-performance) shows that there are packet-per-second limitations on ec2 instances. May be closing/opening the socket on the client side makes the packet rate slow down enough to stay below these limitations.

Comment: Or, if a new client socket is used for each message, the dynamic port it is bound to changes every time a message is sent. This could be interpreted, by an hypothetical limitation process on the ec2 side, as many different/independent communications rather than a single high rate communication.